Office script to get data from table, filtered data and pasted into a new tab and new table
I have been trying to extract filtered data from my "PMs" table in my excel, I need to filter column D for statuses that are equal to "WSCH" or "WAPPR" or "INPRG" and filter column H with values equal or less to 7, once the filter has been applied, create a new tab and paste the filtered data into a new table called PM On Risk, I have tried it for several days but I can't get it.
Thank you very much for your help.
Test01
I try this:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Obtener la tabla "PMs"
  let table: ExcelScript.Table = workbook.getTable("PMs");

  // Filtrar los datos por la columna "Status" igual a "WSCH", "WAPPR" o "INPRG" y la columna "Days till the target end date" menor o igual a 7
  let filteredRange: ExcelScript.Range = table.getRange().getFilteredRange([{
    column: table.getColumnByName("Status").getIndex(),
    operator: "In",
    values: ["WSCH", "WAPPR", "INPRG"]
  }, {
    column: table.getColumnByName("Days till the target end date").getIndex(),
    operator: "LessThanOrEqual",
    values: ["7"]
  }]);

  // Crear una nueva hoja de cálculo llamada "PMRisk"
  let newSheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("PMRisk");

  // Crear una nueva tabla llamada "PM_Notification" en la nueva hoja de cálculo
  let newTable: ExcelScript.Table = newSheet.addTable("PM_Notification", filteredRange, true);

}


You might need to apply the data filters individually, then copy the filtered data to a new sheet.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const dataSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let table: ExcelScript.Table = workbook.getTable("PMs");
    const dataRange = table.getRange();
    // Clear auto filter on table pMs
    const tabFilter = table.getAutoFilter();
    tabFilter.clearCriteria();
    // filter table on Col D and H
    let colIndexD = table.getColumnByName("Status").getIndex(); // Col D
    tabFilter.apply(dataRange,
        colIndexD, {
        filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, 
        values: ["WSCH", "WAPPR", "INPRG"]
    });
    const colIndexH = table.getColumnByName("Days till the target end date").getIndex(); // Col H
    tabFilter.apply(dataRange,
        colIndexH, {
        filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.custom, 
        criterion1: "<=7",
        operator: ExcelScript.FilterOperator.and
    });
    let newSheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("PMRisk");
    if(newSheet){ // clear dest. sheet
        newSheet.getRange().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
    }
    else{ // add dest. sheet
        newSheet = workbook.addWorksheet("PMRisk");
    }
    // copy filter table to new sheet
    newSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(dataRange.getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.visible) );
    // newSheet.activate();
    // add new table
    const newRange = newSheet.getUsedRange();
    const newTable = newSheet.addTable(newRange.getAddress(), true);
    newTable.setName("PM_Notification");
}



